# how to start a firefox with a different WM_CLASS? (or any other altered property like WM_NAME)

Tags: linux, firefox, xorg, i3-window-manager

i'm on mint linux with i3wm

i want to discriminate a special firefox session from the default sessions when its starts. So i need it to have at least one altered property right at the beginning
(later it changes its title but then it is to late. I want to assign it via an i3 command to a special workspace)

i tried this

```
firefox --class="pidgin"
#xprop output: WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"
firefox --class=pidgin
#xprop output: WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"
```

this works:

```
xprop -set WM_NAME "Horst" #this works but its not at startup
#xprop output: WM_NAME(STRING) = "Horst"
```

this dosn't:

```
xprop -set WM_CLASS "Pidgin"
xprop: error: unsupported conversion for WM_CLASS
```

1) how do i check that the
firefox --class=<1>
command works?

2) what is a valid value for <1>?

3) is there any other way/command to start firefox with an altered property?

Answer (score 6):

To address 2), any string does the job:

```
$ firefox --class foo
```

i3 assign catches it (which is enough for me), but `xprop` still shows the old value.

Comment: This works, but only if firefox is not already running.

Comment: @gladed use the `--no-remote` option in combination with `-P profile` if you desire multiple instances of firefox with unique class names. so for example `firefox --no-remote -P default --class foo`.

Comment: Combining this with one-line shell scripts to start firefox alongside with the correct profile and simply using that instead of ``firefox`` to start it works like a charm—at least for those of us who have their browsers open continuously.